# Open tab using anchor tag link on next page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a developing a it service website.

I have a service page where I am using javascript tab to showcase all the service like:-web-development, software development, web-hosting and more.

And on index page I have footer section. In footer I have a section called service in which I have links of service like:-web-development, software development, web-hosting and more.

I want that onclicking on any footer service link it will first go to service page (every anchor tag do). Then open the same footer link tab on service page.

If any one can help me then **PLEACE**

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and read [ask]. Your question currently is broad, vague and unclear and lacks details including debugging details. After you read the guidelines, edit your question and include a [repro] with debugging details of your attempt. Note that SO is not a Forum, tutorial or code-writing-service.

Comment: You can put hashtags or parameter values in the footer links URLs. Then add JavaScript on the service page to read that value and open the corresponding tab.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Just try it.

```
<a href="https://service_page_url/" target="_blank">Try it!</a>
```

Comment: Do not answer on broad, unclear and very vague questions.

Comment: It is going to service page as every anchor tag do but, I want that after going to service page. I want that onclicking on any footer service link it will first go to service page (every anchor tag do). Then open the same footer link tab on service page. Example:- if in footer I am clicking on web-development then  on service page it have to open the web-development service tab.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).